# Conditional Formatting in Access Using Different Fields

Tags: ms-access, conditional-formatting

I have a form with an embedded subform in it. I want to use conditional formatting to change a field in the overall form to have a pink background color if a field in the embedded subform is True (1). So far I have:
Format only cells where the:
Expression Is:

```
Forms!frmSubForm!TextField.Value="True"
```

But this is not working. Any Ideas as to what I am doing wrong?
The value that I am checking for "True" comes from a dbo table from SQL, where the value is 1 if true and 0 if false. Access seems to automatically convert 1's to True and 0's to False in form view. Still, I am not sure if the check for "True" is correct, or if it should check for "1" or 1...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the field type in SQL.  If it's a bit, try something like this:

```
SELECT CAST('TRUE' as bit) -- RETURN 1
SELECT CAST('FALSE' as bit) --RETURN 0
```

If it's varchar or int, that might work as well.

Comment: I just checked, and the data is indeed of bit type. Is there a way to account for this in the expression for the conditional formatting? I don't want to change anything in the SQL dbo.

Comment: Then you'll need to do conditional formatting where Forms!frmSubForm!TextField.Value="1" since it's already a bit.  Double-check the linked table in design view in Access, though, because I'm pretty sure a bit field gets converted to Yes/No in Access.

Comment: yeah, good call. It got pulled in as a Yes/No in Access. Will the check for "1" still work?

Comment: If it's Yes/No, then -1 = True and 0 = False (or I might have that backwards).  It's definitely -1 and 0, though.

Answer (score 1):

The safest way is probably to check for `<> 0`, this avoids the 1 / -1 / True confusion.

```
Forms!frmSubForm!TextField.Value <> 0
```